# Не работают псевдонмы

Tags: php, yii2

Не понимаю, почему этот алиас работает

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@app');
```

а остальные не работают?

```
echo Yii::getAlias('@foo');
```

Пишет ошибку

```
in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\BaseYii.php
throw new InvalidParamException("Invalid path alias: $alias");
```

или это потому что у меня базовая версия?

Answer (score 1):

Эти алиаc негде не описан, его сначала нужно задать, в файлике params.php

```
$foo = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../');    
Yii::setAlias('@foo', $foo);
```

Comment: должно же в коробке идти

Comment: из коробки только несколько предопределено
    [@common] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo\common
    [@frontend] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo/frontend
    [@backend] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo/backend
    [@console] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo/console
    [@app] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo\console
    [@vendor] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo/vendor
    [@runtime] => C:\Users\Prog-7\projects\yepo\console\runtime